# Why the statistics module only returning the name of the column, but not the median value?

Tags: python, pandas, statistics, return, median

[alcohol file](http://www.principlesofeconometrics.com/excel.htm)

```
import pandas as pd
import statistics as st

def median_1(table):
    print(table.median())
    
def median_2(table):
    print(st.median(table))

# Reading the excel file and sorting the value according to the X column
file=pd.read_excel("C:\\Users\\hp\\Desktop\\alcohol.xls").sort_values("X")

#Forming the new index using list comprehension
index_row=[i+1 for i in range(len(file))]

#making the new index compatible
index_new=pd.Index(index_row)

#Extracting the column named X and converting it into dataframe
column_df=pd.DataFrame(file.loc[:,"X"])

#setting the new index 
new=column_df.set_index(index_new)


median_1(new)
median_2(new)
```

Median_1 is returning column name and the median values, but it should be returning only the median value.

The median_2 function is not returning the median value, it is just returning the name of the column.

```
Output:
runfile('C:/Users/hp/Desktop/eg.py', wdir='C:/Users/hp/Desktop')
X    562.5
dtype: float64
X
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

st.median() takes a list not a data frame as input. Since `new` is a data frame, it does not work. You could specify the column when you pass the parameter.

```
median_2(new['X']) 
# this will give you the median value without the column name
562.5
```

The same will also work for `df.median()` also as in your `median_1` function.

```
median_1(new['X'])
# this will also give you the median value without the column name
562.5
```

Comment: can u suggest me how to improve my coding skills or this code is good enough?

Comment: @ChitranshMathur From my experience, you only have to practice coding to be better at it. Try taking coding challenges from codingame, hackerrank etc, that will build your skills.

Comment: I mean should I be using fancy syntaxes and fancy functions? Thank You

Comment: @ChitranshMathur To me, it doesn't matter as long as you achieve your goal